# Solr Highlight matching query terms

Tags: solr, solr-highlight

I am using Solr to do a fuzzy search (e.g., `foo~2 bar~2`). [Highlighting](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/highlighting.html) allows me to highlight matching document fragments from the resultset.

For example:

`Result 1: <em>food</em> <em> bars</em>
Result 2: mars <em>bar</em>`

and so on.

For each match highlighted from the document, I need to figure out which query terms did these fragments matched against along with offsets of those query terms in the query. Something like:

`Result 1: {<em>food</em> MATCHED_AGAINST foo QUERY_OFFSET 0,2} {<em> bars</em> MATCHED_AGAINST bar QUERY_OFFSET 3,5}
Result 2: mars {<em>bar</em> MATCHED_AGAINST bar QUERY_OFFSET 3,5}`

Is there a way to do this in Solr?

Comment: it could be done via custom highlighter

Comment: You could probably write custom code for it, but this is not supported out of the box.

Comment: True, I suppose this is easier in `Lucene`, but looks like I will have to write a plugin. Was hoping if things have changed over last few versions :-)

Comment: @Mysterion, can you please shade some light on what kind of customization I can do here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One hack I could figure out is to use different (unique) `boost` factors for each term in the query, and then retrieving boost factors for each matched term from the `debug` score so as to deduce which term that score came from.

For example, we can query with `foo~2^3.0 bar~2^2.0` (boost scores from bar by 2.0, keep scores from matching against foo untouched). From the debug score output, check the boost factors:

```
Result 1: food bars: score <total score 1> = food * 3.0 * <other scoring terms> + bars * 2.0 * <other scoring terms>
Result 2: mars bar: score <total score 2> = bar * 2.0 * <other scoring terms>
```

From which it is clear that `food` matched with boost factor of `3.0`, and `bars` as well as `bar` matched with boost factor of `2.0`. Maintaining a lookup dictionary for which term had what boost to begin with, it is easy to figure out which terms matched.

Two factors to consider:

1. If the boost factor is `1.0`, solr debug score does not print it.
2. Solr might incorporate some default boost factor for the term based on fuzzy matching, TF-IDF, etc. In this case, the boost factor that shows up will not match against the boosts we supplied in the query. For this reason, we need to execute our query twice - once without any boosting (to understand default boosting for every term), and once with boosting (to see how much it has changed now).

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Unfortunately, debug is something which isn't recommended to be used all time on production system

Comment: Well, this is only a `hack` which can solve the issue without writinga any custom code or plugin :-)

Answer (score 2):

One of the possibility would be to customize Highlighter that will produce needed information. Idea is simple - you have method

```
org.apache.lucene.search.highlight.Highlighter#getBestTextFragments
```

in this method you have low-level access to the QueryScorer which consists of several useful attributes like

```
private Set<String> foundTerms;
private Map<String,WeightedSpanTerm> fieldWeightedSpanTerms;
private Query query;
```

I'm pretty much sure, that using this information you should be able to produce needed output